# Html download with Async Task Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm trying to make a web app using the WebView component. I need to modify the HTML before I show it to the user, so I tried to download it, modify it and the load it. I did this using the HTTP response and get classes and because of a series of exception I had to put them in an AsyncTask. Now the problem is that this solution works but it has a short delay because I have to wait for the Thread to end and then I can call the WebView.load() method either for the home and the other links. It is really ugly...do you have any solution to suggest me? Something without Async Tasks maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The Android documentation states, that you should NEVER perform network operations on the main thread (otherwise, it will give you an exception).
Waiting for the AsyncTask to complete its background workflow is a natural process similar to think over the problem before giving the solution (your brain need to compute it *in the background*, if you will).

Answer (score 0):

You will wait in any case. The server can't provide information instantly. But if you make request not in AsyncTask, it will block your application. And then android will offer to stop it. You dont need it. Instead of this you need to show something like process dialog.